# Is Geoserver not allowing in Cross Domain data access (getFeatureInfo)?

Tags: java, tomcat, cross-domain, shapefile, geoserver

My Geoserver is running on the port 8080(using tomcat 7) & My Application is running on 8084 with different server(tomcat 6).
The shapefile is viewing properly but on click event no feature information coming ,it's always going in waiting mode.
If i'm giving same port & server to run geoserver & application then there is no problem everything is working properly.
but my requirement is to run application & geoserver on different-different port.

Is It possible to make CrossDomain request? Because my requests are denied by the Geoserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is better to use same tomcat port for both geoserver and your application. and refer this link 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20328/path-to-proxy-cgi-for-geoserver-is-not-accessible-in-browser

Comment: Hey @shankaj that i did but my requirement is to run my application on different server & geoserver on different server.